# Access 2003: How to update TableA from TableB based on condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting error "Operation must use an updateable query" with the following code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
update reportbyjobtable 
set [StepAtPP22010]  = (SELECT TOP 1 PTTIMERATE.STEP FROM PTTIMERATE WHERE PTTIMERATE.TIMEREQUIRE<= REPORTBYJOBTABLE.TOTALHOUR93TOPP012010 
ORDER BY PTTIMERATE.TIMEREQUIRE DESC)
where [benefits start date]>#8/28/2010#
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you doing this in a query or does this get executed on a client application?

Comment: Its in a query in Access 2003.

Answer (score 0):

make shure the "reportbyjobtable" is a table, not a query.

try to build another query with the "select" statament wich is used to update the [stepAtPP22010] field. Save this query and build another query using the result column from the first query saved to update the "reportbyjobtable" table. Be care using the correct relationship type between queryes and tables.